# I do not have listItems.js file in my src folder but still It is importing any file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Whenever , I try to run the code, I get below error. I am not using useNavigate anywhere.

Error

[image]

Folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the title, you said that there is no file named `listItems.js` but the file is there but is named `listItems.tsx`.

The problem with this file is they are not following the correct name convention for React, try changing it to `ListItems.tsx`

[listItems.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIzBM.png)

Comment: Hi,  please check the error, it is looking for the listItens.js but in the folder we have listItem.tsx.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error.
**Steps**

1. Clean the npm cache ( npm cache clean )
2. Stop the application.
3. Start app again the error will be rectified.